# Lenovo ideapad 110 - Cannot Detect Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: wireless, lenovo, ideapad

I've tried lshw and lspci, but I cannot detect the wireless network adapter in this laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.5:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is wifi enabled in BIOS settings?

Comment: Hardware issues as per [OP's self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134715/480481)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that this computer wasn't properly assembled at the factory. Its wireless adapter was screwed down to the motherboard, yet not plugged into the motherboard slot at all.

Additionally, the slot itself is defective, the thin copper wires, that are suppose to inline the grooves of the slot were frayed up above the groves on the right side of the slot.

It gets worst, a fresh install of Ubuntu would lock up, even after I replaced its hard drive with a Samsung SSD.

Apparently, I'm not the only person unsatisfied with this laptop; This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULoqv7XgC4I) titles this laptop the worst Laptop of 2017. In 2017, the owner of this laptop put it back in the box with intentions of returning it, but his wife moved it into a closest and it got forgotten about.

I was recently tasked with setting this thing up for someone the original owner wanted to give it to. It looked brand new out of the box when I received it. Ultimately, I **threw it in the trash** so it couldn't cause anymore pain.

Prior to this laptop, I trusted the Lenovo brand name without much scrutiny. From now own, that assumption of quality will not happen. They should never sell anything that terrible; putting their name on that laptop was a mistake that has only tarnished their brand in my mind and apparently others too (see youtube comments).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try your wireless before on Ubuntu 14.04 or 18.04 LTS?

As your BIOS is from June 2017, you might need to try Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Perhaps this new release might support your wireless card, if Ubuntu people did not backport the driver into 16.04.5.

Comment: When I went to Wi-Fi settings using the Ubuntu 18.04.2 Live CD, it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". I'm beginning to think this machine has a hardware defect.

Comment: Don't give up just yet. Ubuntu 19.04 official release is due to be published in just two days, on April 18th 2019. Perhaps it will support your Wi-Fi adapter. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-19-04-release-features/

Comment: From the preview, I see that Ubuntu 19.04 supports Wi-Fi, but I am not saying with certainty that it will support *your* adapter. There is still, of course, the possibility you implied, that of a hardware defect. Just let's try to eliminate all other causes before giving up.

Comment: The question is whether your Wi-Fi works under MS Windows, and if it does, then it is not hardware, but the Ubuntu driver problem. As Ubuntu 19.04 is based on Linux kernel 5.0.x, it is not impossible that it will include the kernel driver you need.